# Advanced Run Time Calculation in R

Tags: r

I once saw somebody run an R script wherein he was able to run a block of code, and then return a matrix of each function that was called in the code and the total amount of time spent computing that particular function.  So for example, I could do:

```
foo{
 for(i in 1:10){
  if(i < 5)
   {print i}
}
```

which return something like

`for: 10 ms`

`if: 2 ms`

`print: 34 ms`

I'd appreciate it if anyone knows the name of the function that does this.

Comment: Did you mean `Rprof`?

Comment: The `profr` package wraps `Rprof` and lets you visualize the profile.

Comment: Thank you, profr/Rprof was what I was looking for.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rprof and profr looked to be the answers; as given in the comments.  Let's get this closed.